# How to find this common solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the system

$$
\ddot{x}=-\frac{k_1 x}{m},~~\ddot{y}=-\frac{k_2 y}{m}
$$
with $k_1,k_2,m > 0$.

How can I solve this? Can you give me a hint?

**Edit**

My idea is to write it this way:

$$
\dot{\omega}=A\omega,~~~A:=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\-\frac{k_1}{m} & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & -\frac{k_2}{m} & 0\end{pmatrix}, \omega:=(x,z_1,y,z_2)^t, z_1:=\dot{x}, z_2:=\dot{y}
$$
So what I have to solve is a linear System with constant coefficients.

Comment: Please share your thought so far :)

Comment: Ok, sorry, I'll add.

Comment: Why can't you solve them separately?

Comment: Ok, then separately! I choose one: $\dot{\omega}=A\omega$ with $$A:=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\-\frac{k_1}{m} & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ and $\omega:=(x,z_1)^t, z_1:=\dot{x}$.

Comment: This decouples: you can solve the equation for $x$ and $y$ separately.

Comment: How do I see that I can solve it separately? Because there is no $y$ in the first and no $x$ in the second ODE?

Comment: @math12 *"Because there is no $y$ in the first and no $x$ in the second ODE?"* Yes, and not only that, if $k_1,k_2$ and $m$ aren't in relation to $x$ or $y$ then you can take and solve each equation apart from one another; that's because there aren't any linear combinations of $x$ and $y$ inside your equations.